# EXTJS vtype regex for non decimal number

Tags: regex, extjs

How do I allow only non decimal numbers from 0-99 in the numberfield. No decimal should be allowed.

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        nonDecimalNumber: function (value) {
          return /^\d$/.test(value);
        },
        nonDecimalNumberText: 'Please enter a valid number without any decimal places'
});

Ext.define('ParameterNumberField', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.field.Number',
  xtype: 'numberfield',
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 90,
  allowBlank: false,
  maskRe: /[0-9.]/,  
  vtype: 'nonDecimalNumber'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the answers. I implemented the following and it works fine

```
nonDecimalNumber: function (value) {
    return  (/^[0-9].*/.test(value) && !(/(\.)/.test(value))); 
  },
  nonDecimalNumberText: 'Enter correct format'
```

Comment: i think this allows `99999999`

Comment: I added added minValue and MaxValue in my ParameterNumberField

Answer (score 1):

> How do I allow only non decimal numbers from 0-99 in the numberfield.

```
^([1-9]\d|\d)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iB9oP9/5)

Note that this regex won't allow numbers like `00` or `01` or `02` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]?[0-9]$
```

This should do it.This will allow numbers from `0` to `99`.